# Buidling navigation bar - LI tag space between words takes to next line

Tags: css

I am building a navigation bar for my website . This navigation bar elements are  dynamic . To fit the elements automatically I have the below code

```
.mytaboptions {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0 10px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;        
    background-color: #305081;    
}

.mytaboptions li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    background-color: #305081;
}

.mytaboptions li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #AAAAAA;
    text-decoration: none;    
}

.mytaboptions li a:hover {
    color: #00788A;
    background: #c7c7c7;
}
.mytaboptions li.active a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DADADA;    
}
.mytaboptions li.selected {
    background: #fafbfd;
    border-bottom:none;    
}

.mytaboptions span{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style:italic;
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

This works fine . But if I have space between words in a tab ( `<li>` tag ) it splits into two lines . If I add `&nbsp;` it works fine .

Please have a look at the below fiddle what I am talking

http://jsfiddle.net/MJEKa/

You can see I used `&nbsp;` in the first nav bar and it looks good . But the second one you see it splits . ( You can see **some other option** in the end )

I am wondering any solution without using `&nbsp;` ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The SPACE and &nbsp; are technically different as fairly explained in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357078/whats-the-difference-between-nbsp-and. Now one way to resolve the issue could be increasing width as per the length of the contents of anchor.

Comment: Thanks Shant for your response . But it is not a length issue . There should be some other way .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `white-space: nowrap;` to stop wrapping of text.

Comment: Thank You Damien Overeem . I used it many times :) But here I was lost . Thanks again . One question , I know it is irrelevant here , but if you see here http://jsfiddle.net/MJEKa/  for counts I am using <br> tag . for example <li><a href="#"> Option2 <br> <span>2000</span></a></li>  . Any trick to avoid <br> tag and get the 2000 in the next line . using too many <br> tags :( Thank You again

Comment: clear: both often helps :) or display: block (which allways makes the element go to a new line)

Comment: Thank You . I already used  display: block in Li a tag . But for new line .. I don't see that is helping . display:block gives me vertical if I use it directly in <li> tag . I removed br tag here in the first element and you can see the count came up .. http://jsfiddle.net/MJEKa/3/