# selectmenu indent text in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've a select. And I want to have a cascading display between parent and child. All is dynamic.
I want something

```
Parent1
  |---Child1
  |---Child2
  |     |---Child21
  |     |     |---Child211
  |     |---Child22
Parent2
```

...
I write this code:

```
 $(function () {
    GetlstParents();
    $("#lstFiltreFamParent").selectmenu().selectmenu("menuWidget").addClass("lstFiltreoverflow");

    });

    function GetlstParents() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Classement/Interne.aspx/GetlstParents",
        data: '{"PageEnCours":"' + document.location.href.toString() + '"}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d.Retour.Reussi) { BuildLstParents(msg.d.LstParents); }
            else { AfficheMsgRetour(msg.d.Retour); }
        },
        error: function () { AfficheMsgRetour({ Reussi: false, Titre: "Liste des classements   parents", Msg: "Erreur accès fonction." }); }
    });
    }

    function BuildLstParents(Lst) {
    var LaList = $("#lstFiltreFamParent");
    $('option', "#lstFiltreFamParent").remove();
    //var Spacelst = "|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    var Spacelst = "|         ";
    $.each(Lst, function (i, item) {
        LaList.append($('<option>', { value: item.Id,  text: Spacelst.repeat(item.Depth -1) +"|--- " +  item.DisplayName }));
    });
    }
```

It's run perfect, the only problem is the white space are smaller than a letter. And the display is not really good. 
I've 3 choises

1. change font ... I prefer solution work with all font
2. replace white space by ...?
3. use CSS : but how put recurcive ?

Comment: You best bet would be to use monospace fonts.

Comment: But i use jquery ui plugin ... I don't want modify the style. solution : function BuildLstParents(Lst) {
    var LaList = $("#lstFiltreFamParent");
    $('option', "#lstFiltreFamParent").remove();
    var Spacelst = "|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    //var Spacelst = "|     ";
    $.each(Lst, function (i, item) {
        $('<option id="' + item.Id + '">' + Spacelst.repeat(item.Depth - 1) + "|--- " + item.DisplayName + '</option>').appendTo(LaList);
        //LaList.append($('<option>', { value: item.Id,  text: Spacelst.repeat(item.Depth -1) +"|--- " +  item.DisplayName }));
    });
} why?

Comment: What difference between " " and "&nbsp;"? Sorry I don't post a proper solution I've no vote

Comment: You will not be able to align properly, because other fonts would be proportional and hence the spaces will also differ accordingly. Best bet is to use monospace font family backed by a generic "monospace" font. Just like `code` and `pre` tags.

Comment: Read : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357078/whats-the-difference-between-nbsp-and) It's my response. Better use "&nbsp;" not " ".

Comment: `&nbsp;` is non-breaking space. Normal spaces if more than  one will be coalesced into one. Hence non-breaking spaces are used when spaces are to be used literally. In your use-case you need non-breaking spaces because you are using them to indent. Otherwise, with regards to your original question, to have symmetric indents, you have to use monospace fonts.

Comment: i'm sorry to hurt you, it wasn't my will. But I don't share your thinking, that's all. And now I Know "&nbsp;" i search about this, and find lot of people (on stackoverflow ans other) with same problem and they solved with "&nbsp;" then I think I'm not stupid, cause I solve my problem with "&nbsp;". I repeat, When You choose font, color ... for your WebSite, You don't modify all, just for a small displaying error's. Customers have their chart, and you need to respect that.

Comment: I think its my problem then if I am unable to explain clearly. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rmdv4tao/ Hope now you get the idea. If you use a monospace font in your style, then it will always work uniformly. But, if you rely on your theme then whenever you change your theme, the spacing will change. By, using a monospace font you make your site immune to style changes. I think I cannot say anything more than that. Good luck.

Comment: I understand why you say use a monospace font. it was a solution I think before, but I can't change the font. It's my customer who imposes the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change a little my mind. Its better to let custom list in local machin, not by the server
Then in jquery, I create a function

```
function BuildLstParents(Lst) {
var LaList = $("#lstFiltreFamParent");
$('option', "#lstFiltreFamParent").remove();
var Spacelst = "|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$.each(Lst, function (i, item) { $('<option id="' + item.Id + '">' + (item.Depth==0?item.DisplayName.capitalize():Spacelst.repeat(item.Depth - 1) + "|--- " + item.DisplayName.capitalize()) + '</option>').appendTo(LaList); });
}
```

Comment: An easier way is to just add multiple spaces at the beginning of your strings for the options.