# How do you wrap contents with &nbsp;?

Tags: html, css, web

I have some content with `&nbsp;` and it doesn't wrap it correctly. So the only solution I had was to use `word-break: break-all` however it splits the word as well. I am guessing that `&nbsp;` is getting treated like a letter? So is there a way to handle `&nbsp;` differently from a letter so that it could be broken but not the words as such?

```css
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1pt solid;
}
.wrapme{
  white-space: wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapme">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/j6hpovbo/

Difference between `&nbsp;` and `" "` is explained in [What's the difference between "&nbsp;" and " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357078/whats-the-difference-between-nbsp-and)

Comment: Why do you want to break a non-breaking space in the first place?

Comment: The entire point of a non-breaking space is to have a space where word wrapping does not occur. Fix your data instead of trying to hack around it.

Comment: Thats a good question, its coming from an external source which we don't have control over. So first I was thinking if I could provide a hack to make it work. Something like treat &nbsp; different from a letter? If thats not at all possible I would pass it  on as non-handleable and fix-your-data!

Comment: You can make a js line that replaces that. Something like `$('.wrapme td').text().replace("&nbsp;", " ");` and you'll get all spaces

Comment: Transform your data before rendering it. Once you've fetched it from your external source simply perform a string replacement to replace `&nbsp;` with an actual space. You can do this server-side *or* client-side.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I tried that https://jsfiddle.net/gyvw4n87/6/ but not quite working? Can you update that fiddle? An issue with replace all? Yes it was just that! Fixed it in https://jsfiddle.net/gyvw4n87/7/

Comment: @Nishant if you use jquery `text()` function it replaces automatically. `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).text());
  });
});`

Comment: Do you want to move this as an answer? Or I will go ahead and select @Moob answer. Problem is you both did it at about the same time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transform your data before rendering it. Once you've fetched it from your external source simply perform a string replacement to replace `&nbsp;` with an actual space. You can do this server-side or client-side. Server-side is probably best but here's a basic JavaScript solution:

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
for (i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i) {
  tds[i].innerHTML = tds[i].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td>LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;LoremIspum&nbsp;
</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j6hpovbo/2/

In that solution there is no need to provide styling property to `.wrapme` class.
By applying width this issue will resolve.

Comment: I don't want to preserve the words i.e it should not break a word.

Comment: if you dont want to break whole word then you will have to apply width otherwise you can remove width property from table which is given

Comment: In your fiddle, words are breaking - can you show me an example where it doesn't? I would love a CSS solution!

Comment: var str = $('.wrapme td').text();
str.replace('&nbsp;', '');
$('..wrapme td').text(str);

Comment: Something like this could work. But with CSS, isn't posible i guess.