# Forcing a word to wrap

Tags: html, css, word-break

How can I make the word "Hameln" take on a new line instead of breaking?

I've tried experimenting with `overflow-wrap`, `word-break`, & `white-space` but either the word breaks or it overflows beyond the container. It never talked a new line between "31789" and "Hameln".

```html
<span class="standort-adresse-strasse"> Grabbestraße&nbsp;23&nbsp;|&nbsp;31789&nbsp;Hameln </span>
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could probably add some padding to your wrapper element, so it does not extend all the way to the right and goes under scrollbar (-gutter).

Comment: ```.standort-adresse-strasse{padding-right:1rem;}``` will probably fix this, and don't use ```word-break``` on it.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `&nbsp;` between all of your other words? By definition, that is a _non-breaking_ space, so the browser is interpreting all of that text as a single word. Removing the `&nbsp;` before `Hameln` will allow it to "break" onto its own line if needed.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried wrapping only "Hameln" in nowrap? Like so: `<span style="white-space: nowrap">Hameln</span>`

Comment: @prettyInPink No, That just adds some padding to the "meln" part

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones This might be it. The HTML comes from a PHP template (Wordpress).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Duplicate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743681/how-do-you-wrap-contents-with-nbsp