# BeautifulSoup4 soup.find('tag', text=re.compile('my text')) only working sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a specific way of pulling text out of the fallowing html.

```
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Close Date:</td>
<td> June 19, 2008</td>
```

My Question is why something like:

```
soup.find('td', text=re.compile('Close'))
```

returns:

```
<td>Close Date:</td>
```

However, when I try to do something more specific it returns nothing.

```
soup.find('td', text=re.compile('Close Date:'))
```

I would like to make the script as specific as possible so that I can run it through multiple webpages without picking up erroneous text.

Comment: Does `soup.find('td', text=re.compile('Close\s+Date:'))` work? This would match 1-or-more whitespaces between `Close` and `Date` -- which might be helpful if the space is actually a [non-breaking space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1357078/190597) (i.e. `&nbsp;`)

Comment: @unutbu I don't believe `\s` matches `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Yes! That did work! Much Obliged

Comment: @DYZ: BeautifulSoup parses the HTML, so by the time `soup.find` is called, the `&nbsp;` would already have been converted to `'\xa0'` (a [no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)).

Comment: @unutbu Ok, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a non-breaking space between `Close` and `Date`. In that case, you could use `\s+` to match 1-or-more whitespaces:

```
print(soup.find('td', text=re.compile('Close\s+Date:')))
```

---

For example,

```
import re
import bs4 as bs

content = '''\
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Close&nbsp;Date:</td>
<td> June 19, 2008</td>
'''

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('td', text=re.compile('Close\s+Date:')))
```

yields

```
<td>Close Date:</td>
```