# div ignore start spaces and more then 1 space

Tags: html, angular

the problem is that every space char at the start of the text is being discarded and every second space char afterwards is being discarded as well.

this is the example, treat every '_' char as "space" because it happening here as well:

text : "____a_a__a_______a"

visual : "a a a a"

the part of the angular 2 code that rendering the text is this:

```
<div #refId class = 'line_counter' [ngStyle]=setStyles()>
{{getData()}}
</div>
```

the solution i thought of is using some predefined char and render it as transparent but im really hopping that some one could help me with a real solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform blank spaces inside the IDE and expect to visual it while running.

You must add [`&nbsp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357078/whats-the-difference-between-nbsp-and) to your text value, this way you will be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this HTML entity: `&nbsp;`

this stands for "non-breaking space", and you can put as many after each other as you like.