# replace &nbsp; with carriage return

Tags: mysql

I need something like this:

```
update notes set story = replace(story, "&nbsp;", "carriage_return";
```

so this:

```
&nbsp;
LOREM
&nbsp;
IPSUM
```

should become:

```
LOREM

IPSUM
```

Any help?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Where do you want to actually view the result set?  From MySQL or from some other tool which is using MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I want to get the returns on client side, i.e. inside a textarea, after selecting `story` on server side

Comment: Your example shows '&nbsp;' being replaced by an empty string (or a space).   BTW '&nbsp;' is a [non-breaking-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357078/whats-the-difference-between-nbsp-and/1357090)

Comment: @Luuk where do you see a space in my example?

Comment: @qadenza: On the line between `LOREM` and `IPSUM`.

Comment: @Luuk there is no any space between `LOREM` and `IPSUM`. Copy - Paste the text into an editor and show hidden characters.

Comment: Ok, I should have re-read my own comment saying `"Your example shows '&nbsp;' being replaced by an empty string"`, but unfortunately no reaction on the statement that a `&nbsp;` is normally translated to a 'space'.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like below:

```
update notes set story = replace(story, '&nbsp;', '\n');
```

Comment: Can you post your syntax error? Error message that you are getting.

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''&nbsp)' at line 1`

Comment: Can you also COPY and PASTE the EXACT command you used? (Please!)