# How to find an element containing @nbsp; in text?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I've an element with html -

```
<h3>App-1 Playground&nbsp;Login</h3>
```

I want to identify it with entire text - `App-1 Playground Login`, but `&nbsp;` causing issues to identify it. Please help how this element can be identified.

Comment: I think space should not create any issue while you locate like `//h3[contains(.,'App-1 Playground Login')]`

Comment: @NarendraR, this did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @NarendraR My friend he has got &nbsp; in between the texts. &nbsp; is different from the normal space in html.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357078/whats-the-difference-between-nbsp-and

Comment: Try the `partial` text `//h3[contains(.,'App-1 Playground') and contains(.,'Login')]`

Comment: Yes, this is also good solution but if text sequence changes it won't identify the issue.

Comment: Well `if text sequence changes it won't identify the issue` can you provide some example what bothering you?

Comment: Suppose, text on page changes from `App-1 Playground Login` to `Login App-1 Playground` still with given xpath, it'll succeed. Change in text won't cause it to fail.

Comment: If you don't know the order sequence but know the `partial` string then split it further.`//h3[contains(.,'App-1') and contains(.,'Playground') and contains(.,'Login')]`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below xpath. I have already tested that and it is working fine. In the second argument of the translate method you need to type "ALT+0160" and in the third argument you will have to put just a normal space.

```
//h3[contains(translate(text(),' ',' ' ), 'App-1 Playground Login')]
```

Comment: This also did not work :( I did exactly what you've mentioned for arguments.

Comment: I will share my code with you. Just try with that :)

Comment: Please download the below project and maybe you need to update the chrome driver path and just start the execution of it and let me know if you face any issue.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W0aoCqEqp-SPBw_NH6IKbF-KQsXDMraH

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to select your title could be :

```
//h3[text()= concat('App-1 Playground',codepoints-to-string(160),'Login')]
```

Works fine on http://xpather.com/