# How can I add horizontal spaces between text on html5?

Tags: html

I want to add space between text inline without **`pre`** tag. But how. I want only the HTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `&nbsp;` to add space inline with text.

These answers are also an interesting read: [What's the difference between "&nbsp;" and " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1357078/3049893)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the vertical gap between lines of text to be bigger/smaller you need to add a style atribute and set line height.

```
<div style="line-height: 100px;">
  <p>qwerty</p>
  </br>
  <p>qwerty</p>
</div>
```

Or if horizontal space is what you want then you can add more spaces in the text itself or seperate the text into seperate tags and add a style atribute to change their margins.

```
<p style="display:inline;">qwerty</p>
<p style="margin-left: 20px; display: inline;">qwerty</p>
```