# Add whitespace in Vue

Tags: vue.js, whitespace

I have Vue project
I need to insert a whitespace between two parts of words which are in different HTML tags.
How can I do it in Vue? I tried several ways but Vue always delete it

```
<div v-if="film_data.actors" class="film-info__actors">
  actors:    //after ':' I need a whitespace
  <div class="actors">
    {{film_data.actors.join(', ')}}
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.film-info {
  @include h4Text;
  color: $color-dark-gray;

  &__actors {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

.actors {
  @include bodyText;
  color: $color-light-gray;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357163/2185093

Comment: html does not allow stacking regular space; it is a feature of HTML, not vue. You need margin/padding at the start/end parts of related html elements or special breaks (though styling should be preferred to special breaks if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Vue is not supposed to be removing whitespace. The part were you want to insert whitespace is just plain HTML. Maybe you can just add some right padding?

```
<div v-if="film_data.actors" class="film-info__actors">
  <span style='padding-right: 50px'>actors:</span>
  <div class="actors">
    {{film_data.actors.join(', ')}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is the &nbsp; character. But if its just to create spacing this is usually not a good idea.